# ¿Por qué mis archivos aparecen bloqueados en owncloud?

Tags: c#, centos

Tengo un servidor WebDAV desarollado en C# al cual quiero conectar mediante owncloud (alojado en centos) y realizar transferencia de archivos, el problema con esto es que cuando intento subir archivos me aparece un mensaje que dice "lock" y mis archivos no aparecen. Al conectar a mi servidor WebDAV mediante algún cliente como BitKinex puedo visualizar el archivo pero no puedo recuperarlo o cambiarle el nombre.

Si intento subir ese mismo archivo con otro nombre entonces si se me permite hacerlo sin problema alguno, pero no entiendo porque me causa conflicto con el nombre anterior y como sistema de producción no puedo pedir a todos los usuarios que cambien el nombre de sus archivos.

Alguna idea de por qué sucede esto y como solucionarlo sería de gran ayuda.